# A distribution on binary vectors defined by a sum

Tags: probability, distributions

The following distribution came up in my research and I'm wondering if the general class has a name and if there are computationally efficient sampling methods for it.

Let $\mathcal{X} = \{0,1\}^{n}$ be the sample space; these are simply $n$ dimensional vectors with each component either $0$ or $1$. Let $a_1,...,a_n$ be non-negative coefficients with atleast one $a_i$ positive. Then define the measure 
$$P(x_1,...,x_n) = \frac{1}{Z}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_ix_i$$
where $Z$ is a normalization constant (a simple recursion shows $Z = 2^{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_i)$.

Does this distribution look familiar to anyone? Please include a reference to a textbook or scholarly article in your response.

Answer (score -1):

It's multinomial distribution. Same as repeating a coin toss n times and count the number of times head appears. In this case you also have coefficient to each i th toss ( i= 1..n) means that you have treat ith toss differently from the i+1 th toss.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Care to elaborate on this? The probability mass function for the multinomial distribution on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution looks very different, there is no sum involved.

Comment: P is clearly not probability but a statistics defined. Or you need to give me an example what kind of process or events does this distribution describe.

Comment: **This answer looks incorrect.** For instance, let $n=2$ and set $a_1=2,a_2=1.$ Then $P(0,0)=0,$ $P(0,1)=1/6,$ $P(1,0)=1/3,$ and $P(1,1)=1/2$ is not a multinomial distribution and is not counting heads.